# Postman GraphQL - Schema Fetch - Authorisation

Tags: oauth, graphql, postman

I am using Postman to test my GraphQL layer and Postman has a handy GraphQL designer for the BODY of the request. It also has a nifty feature for doing a Schema Fetch

If your GraphQL endpoint is secured with OAuth, you normally set the Authorization page to pass the token. All good so far.

However, if your authorization token is set as a collection / environment variable, it does not work because the translation from variable to content does not appear to be happening

How to reproduce.

1. Create a Postman collection / environment variable for your token (it can be anything for now)
2. Open your GraphQL request
3. Switch to the **Authorization** tab
4. Set the Authorization Type to `Bearer Token`
5. Set the Authorization Token to `{{variable-as-per-step-1}}`
6. Switch to the **Body** tab
7. Change the *body content type* to *GraphQL* (This will then show "Fetch" buttons)
8. Click the *refresh* button for the fetch

What happens is that this sends the Authorization header as `Bearer {{variable-as-per-step-1}}` to the endpoint, it does not substitute the variable with the actual content of the variable (which it does when you *SEND* the request.

If you update the Authorization Token to an actual value (rather than variable), then everything works as intended.

Comment: Currently have an open issue for this - https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/10773